# elementary OS Freya Wingpanel is flickering/blinking when window is in fullscreen

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

I have searched a long time but couldn't find a bug or a problem like mine.

So when I start elementary OS and I open any program and make the window fullscreen my wingpanel goes crazy.
It starts to blink/flicker white across the whole wingpanel all the time. I don't really know how to describe it any other way but it's driving me nuts. I am also running windows 10 on this machine and ran Linux Mint like 4 weeks ago and I never experienced something like this.

What i've done to fix it:

1. I tried logging off/on and restarting many times but the problem        persists.
2. I tried reinstalling elementary OS.
3. I typed `pkill wingpanel` and hoped wingpanel just needs to be resetted.
4. I got the "dconf Editor" via `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` and went to org-->pantheon-->desktop-->wingpanel and switched off the "auto-adjust-alpha" option and set the "background-alpha" option to "0.0" because I thought it only happens when the wingpanel is black. But it also happens when it's transparent.
5. I typed `gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel background-alpha 0.35` in terminal but it seemed to be the same option as in the "dconf Editor".
6. I tried different display resolutions.

I'm not an expert on linux systems so I don't really know what to do anymore because I cant' find anything that could help me with google.
If you guys have questions feel free to ask. English is not my mothers tongue so please be kind with me :)

Hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Intel chipset maybe you can try :

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

echo -e 'Section "Device"\n Identifier "Intel Graphics"\n Driver "Intel"\n Option "AccelMethod" "sna"\n Option "TearFree" "true"\nEndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

sudo reboot
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1435861

Comment: That doesn't help. Anyways thank you for your suggestion :)